# Fullcalendar's events not correctly displayed using custom event render template

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am working on simple reservation system which is besides Laravel for backend using fullcalendar to display events from database.
Everything works fine, until I try to return custom event template with code:

```
...,
eventRender: function(event,$el) {
   return $('<p>'+event.title+'</p>');
},
...
```

Events are still displayed on correct days and have correct title, but the margin from top is not correct according to time range it has.

Here is image with default event template:
[image]

And here is image with my template described before:
[image]

I am using fullcalendar library version 3.1.0 and jquery 3.3.1.
When I try using version 2.0 it works, but I really don't want to use library so out dated.

Comment: 3.1 is also outdated - the last version in the 3.x series is 3.10.1. And anyway version 4 has been available for a year, and version 5 is being developed at the moment! So I wouldn't start a new project based on 3.1 anymore.

Comment: P.S. the problem with your code is you replaced the entire HTML of the event with just the `<p>`, so it lost all the formatting etc added by fullCalendar. You need to replace only the title element. Use your browser's Developer Tools to see the HTML structure of a rendered element, and then you'll know better how to replace just the necessary part.

Comment: Thank you ADyson for your reply! Well my goal is not to change the title, but change te whole event div. I already inspected it with developer console, but the only thing that was different was the style variable inset.
I will probably just update fullcalendar library to version 4 or 5, I hope it will work.

Comment: v5 is not released yet, so best to upgrade to the last version 4.4. Make sure you read the upgrade guide: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3 , there are some significant differences.

Comment: "the only thing that was different was the style variable inset"...not sure what you mean really. Your code replaces a `<div>` containing lots of other sections within it for a simple `<p>`. That's a lot more dramatic than just changing the style.